# Multithreading problem in Python - How can i make this work properly?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, queue

```
import queue
import threading

class Cube():
def __init__(self, lat):
    self.lat = lat
    

def volume(self):
    return self.lat ** 3
    

def lenght(self):
    return self.lat * 12


if __name__ == "__main__":
que = queue.Queue()
cube = Cube(2)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda c, q: q.put(c.lenght()), args=(cube, que))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda c, q: q.put(c.volume()), args=(cube, que))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
while not que.empty():
    result = que.get()
    
    print(result)
```

Hello! My program has to calculate the volume and the total lenght of a cube and print all of thoose in to threads. The threads doesn't start...what i should modify? It has to return me 4 results.

Comment: you mean 2 results? also your code works if you indent it properly

Comment: For each object i need to launch 2 threads and execute methods in some order.

Comment: so each thread needs to calculate both length and volume?

Comment: one thread for volume and one for lenght .Each has to launch twice. Don't understand why, but this i have to do...

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating a worker function instead of trying to encapsulate that logic using `lambda`. If I understand correctly you want four threads in total. Conversely, you can have each thread just calculate the output twice. Your code becomes the following when you have four threads.

```
import queue
import threading

NUM_ITERS = 2


class Cube():
    def __init__(self, lat):
        self.lat = lat
        
    def volume(self):
        return self.lat ** 3
        
    def length(self):
        return self.lat * 12


def worker(cube, q, attr):
    func = getattr(cube, attr)
    val = func()
    q.put(val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    que = queue.Queue()
    cube = Cube(2)
    threads = []
    for _ in range(NUM_ITERS):
        for attr in ("length", "volume"):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(cube, que, attr))
            threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    while not que.empty():
        result = que.get()
        
        print(result)
```

The other option as mentioned, is having each thread perform the logic twice, and that is shown below.

```
import queue
import threading

NUM_ITERS = 2


class Cube():
    def __init__(self, lat):
        self.lat = lat
        
    def volume(self):
        return self.lat ** 3
        
    def length(self):
        return self.lat * 12


def worker(cube, q, attr):
    for num in range(NUM_ITERS):
        func = getattr(cube, attr)
        val = func()
        q.put(val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    que = queue.Queue()
    cube = Cube(2)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(cube, que, "length"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(cube, que, "volume"))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    while not que.empty():
        result = que.get()
        
        print(result)
```